# Overloading the assignment operator= doesn't work for anything except the implicit object passed in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

The comparison in the assignment operator works as expected, but when I try to use a temp variable and load then return that, all it returns is the defaults. Debugs show that the values are default 1 x 4, but I'm not sure what to with it to make it fill the temp variables and return them. Everything I've gone through says it should work.

Debug info:

```
-       poly    {coefficient="2" variable="x" exponent="4" }    Polynomial
+       coefficient "2" std::string
+       variable    "x" std::string
+       exponent    "4" std::string
-       poly2   {coefficient="3" variable="x" exponent="4" }    Polynomial
+       coefficient "3" std::string
+       variable    "x" std::string
+       exponent    "4" std::string
-       poly3   {coefficient="1" variable="x" exponent="4" }    Polynomial
+       coefficient "1" std::string
+       variable    "x" std::string
+       exponent    "4" std::string
```

main

```
    // Demonstrating class Polynomial's overloaded stream insertion 
// and stream extraction operators.
#include <iostream>

#include "Polynomial.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {


    Polynomial poly; // create object poly
    Polynomial poly2; // create object poly
    Polynomial poly3; // create object poly
    Polynomial poly4; // create object poly
    Polynomial poly5; // create object poly


    cout << "Enter polynomial number in the form 2x4:" << endl;
    // cin >> phone invokes operator>> by implicitly issuing
    // the non-member function call operator>>(cin, phone)
    cin >> poly;
    cout << "\nThe polynomial number entered was:\n";
    // cout << phone invokes operator<< by implicitly issuing
    // the non-member function call operator<<(cout, phone)
    cout << poly << endl;
    cout << "Enter polynomial number in the form 2x4:" << endl;
    // cin >> phone invokes operator>> by implicitly issuing
    // the non-member function call operator>>(cin, phone)
    cin >> poly2;
    cout << "\nThe polynomial number entered was:\n";
    // cout << phone invokes operator<< by implicitly issuing
    // the non-member function call operator<<(cout, phone)
    cout << "poly2 " << poly2 << endl;
    poly3 = poly + poly2;
    cout << "poly3 " << poly3 << endl;
    poly4 = poly - poly2;
    cout << "poly4 " << poly4 << endl;
    poly5 = poly;
    cout << "poly5 " << poly5 << endl;
  }
```

Header

```
#pragma once
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Polynomial {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Polynomial&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Polynomial&);

public:
    // Default Constructor

    Polynomial(std::string coefficient = "1", std::string variable = "x",
        std::string exponent = "4");

    // Copy Constructor
    Polynomial(const Polynomial& copy)
        : coefficient{ copy.coefficient }, variable{ copy.variable },
        exponent{ copy.exponent } {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    void setPolynomial(std::string, std::string, std::string);
    Polynomial getPolynomial();
    // addition operator; Polynomial + Polynomial
    Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial&) const;
    // subtraction operator; Polynomial - Polynomial
    Polynomial operator-(const Polynomial&) const;
    // assigment operator; Polynomial - Polynomial
    Polynomial operator=( Polynomial&);

private:
    std::string coefficient; // 
    std::string variable;    // 
    std::string exponent;    // 
};

#endif
```

Polynomial.cpp

```
// Overloaded stream insertion and stream extraction operators
// for class PhoneNumber.
#include "Polynomial.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// default constructor; conversion constructor that converts
Polynomial::Polynomial(std::string co, std::string va, std::string ex) {}
// Setters
void Polynomial::setPolynomial(std::string co, std::string va, std::string ex) {
    this->coefficient = co;
    this->variable = va;
    this->exponent = ex;
}
// Getters
Polynomial Polynomial::getPolynomial() { return *this; }
// overloaded stream insertion operator; cannot be a member function
// if we would like to invoke it with cout << somePhoneNumber;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Polynomial& number) {
    output << "Coefficient: " << number.coefficient
        << "\nVariable: " << number.variable
        << "\nExponent: " << number.exponent << "\n"
        << "" << number.coefficient << "" << number.variable << "^"
        << number.exponent << "\n";
    return output; // enables cout << a << b << c;
}

// overloaded stream extraction operator; cannot be a member function
// if we would like to invoke it with cin >> somePhoneNumber;
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Polynomial& number) {
    input >> setw(1) >> number.coefficient; // input area code
    input >> setw(1) >> number.variable;    // input exchange
    input >> setw(1) >> number.exponent;    // input line
    return input;                           // enables cin >> a >> b >> c;
}

// addition operator; Polynomial + Polynomial
// A member function takes an implicit first parameter
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial& op1) const {
    Polynomial temp; // temporary result

    if (this->variable == op1.variable) {
        if (this->exponent == op1.exponent) {
            // Use stoi string to int
            int num1 = stoi(this->coefficient);
            int num2 = stoi(op1.coefficient);
            // use to_string to set coefficient
            std::string s = std::to_string(num1 + num2);
            temp.coefficient = s;
            temp.variable = this->variable;
            temp.exponent = this->exponent;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Exponents must match\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Variables must match\n";
    }
    return temp; // return copy of temporary object
}
// substraction operator; Polynomial - Polynomial
// A member function takes an implicit first parameter
Polynomial Polynomial::operator-(const Polynomial& op1) const {
    Polynomial temp; // temporary result

    if (this->variable == op1.variable) {
        if (this->exponent == op1.exponent) {
            // Use stoi string to int
            int num1 = stoi(this->coefficient);
            int num2 = stoi(op1.coefficient);
            // use to_string to set coefficient
            std::string s = std::to_string(num1 - num2);
            temp.coefficient = s;
            temp.variable = this->variable;
            temp.exponent = this->exponent;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Exponents must match\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Variables must match\n";
    }
    return temp; // return copy of temporary object
}

// assignment operator; Polynomial - Polynomial
// A member function takes an implicit first parameter
Polynomial Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial& op1){
    // self assignment guard
    if (this == &op1) {
        return *this;//This returns as expected.
        // 
    } // This should create a new temp, assign the second's info to it and return it.
    // But all it does is return the default constructor values 1x4
    Polynomial temp;
    temp.coefficient = op1.coefficient;
    temp.variable = op1.variable;
    temp.exponent = op1.exponent;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You don't need an overloaded assignment operator for `Polynomial`.   All of the members are `std::string`, which are safely copyable and assignable without any outside "help" from the programmer.  As a matter of fact, you are messing things up with your version: `Polynomial Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial& op1)` -- that should return a reference to the current `Polynomial`, not a brand new Polynomial.

Comment: And the custom copy constructor is also unnecessary.

Comment: ^^^ and if you were inclined to do so anyway, `Polynomial operator=( Polynomial&);` isn't the way to do it. The return type should be a reference, the argument should be either a value (for swap) or const reference, and the code you have for "self-assignment guard" is highly misleading, since absolutely nothing in that incorrect assignment operator modifies `*this` to begin with. Delete both the copy-assignment and copy-ctor implementations. Your class doesn't need to reinvent them, as the defaults are sufficient.

Comment: The moral of the story is to not write functions that you do not need to write.  The compiler defaults will copy the members without error, optimally, and safely.  Once you stepped in and wrote your own copy/assignment functions, you told the compiler you knew what you were doing, so the compiler let you go on your way to open yourself up for bugs to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial.cpp:

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator=( Polynomial op1)  {
    // self assignment guard
    if (this == &op1) {
        return *this;
        // Do the copy
  }
    Polynomial temp;
    this->coefficient = op1.coefficient;
    this->variable = op1.variable;
    this->exponent = op1.exponent;
    return temp;
}
```

Polynomial.h

```
 Polynomial operator=( Polynomial) ;
```

Comment: This explains very little, and remains wrong, e.g. there is no reason to check for self-assignment when receiving by value (it's literally impossible for `this == &op1` to be true), and you're making a `temp` that serves no purpose (it should be returning `*this` under all circumstances, and returning it by reference).

Comment: I pass by value and return temp. I've tried to get it to work, but it does the same thing your way or mine. ```Polynomial Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial op1) {    
        return *this;
}``` The self assignment check is how the reference says to do it.

Comment: The self-assignment check makes sense *if* you are receiving by reference (because you might have written `Polynomial foo(...);` and then at some later point, done the equivalent of `foo = foo;`; if you receive by reference, `*this == op1` could be true). The version here receives by *value*, so even if you did `foo = foo;`, it would *copy* the original `foo` as a brand new `Polynomial` (received as `op1`), which couldn't possibly be the same object as `*this`.

Comment: And you say "you return `temp`", which is technically true, but useless. You never *assign* to `temp`, so as written, this `operator=`: 1) Needlessly makes a copy of the value provided to it (into `op1`), 2) Makes an extra `Polynomial` `temp`, 3) Copies all the values from `op1` into the fields of `this` (which is fine, given all the attributes are `std::string`; it would be wrong if you copied unmanaged heap-allocated pointers), ignoring `temp` completely, and 4) Returns the still unchanged bare `temp`, which remains unrelated to `this` in any way, as if it were the object assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator=` makes no sense. There are two reasonable ways to implement `operator=`:

1. Using [the copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/364696), where the prototype for `Polynomial` would be:

   ```
     Polynomial& operator=(Polynomial other);
   //^^^^^^^^^^^ Returns a reference
                           ^^^^^^^^^^ Receives argument by value
   ```

   or,
2. "The hard way" (reimplementing stuff `swap` could do for you, and possibly implementing two different versions, one for copy assignment, and an optional one for move assignment), where the prototypes are:

   ```
     Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial& other);
   //^^^^^^^^^^^ Returns a reference
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Receives argument by const reference for copying
     Polynomial& operator=(Polynomial&& other);
   //^^^^^^^^^^^ Returns a reference
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Receives argument by r-value reference for moving
   ```

   and both versions need to handle the possibility of self-assignment, manually implement the individual copies/moves, etc., or
3. The correct way for non-resource managing classes, follow [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero): Every class should *either* manage an unmanaged resource (and nothing else), providing a copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor (in C++11, adding a move constructor and move assignment operator) or use solely managed resources and provide *none* of the above; the compiler will generate good ones for you.

Your original code was clearly going for option #2; [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72050944/364696) uses option #1's prototype, while still following option #2's template (involving a pointless self-assignment check), and on top of that, it does a crazy thing of *not returning a reference to the object just assigned to* (instead returning a temporary object that is never initialized to anything useful, and has nothing to do with any of the objects involved).

The minimalist solution here is to just fix your `operator=` for option #2 (since you've been told you should do a self-assignment check, and this is the only design that needs one):

Polynomial.cpp:

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial& op1)  {  // Changed to return by reference, and accept by const reference
    // self assignment guard
    if (this == &op1) {
        return *this;
    }
    // No need to declare Polynomial temp; the target of the assignment is *this, the source is op1, there's no reason for a third unrelated Polynomial
    this->coefficient = op1.coefficient;
    this->variable = op1.variable;
    this->exponent = op1.exponent;
    return *this;  // Returning *this by reference adheres to the protocol; you've just assigned, and the result of the expression is the object assigned to
}
```

Polynomial.h

```
Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial&); // Same change as in .cpp, to return by ref, accept by const ref
```

That said, this is a silly solution. Your `Polynomial` contains nothing but `std::string` (and logically seems to have no reason for anything but `variable` to even be that; both `coefficient` and `exponent` seem like they should be an integer, floating point, or complex type, depending on use case), which is a managed type; adhering to the Rule of Zero would mean your class needn't implement copy assignment at all, nor copy construction, move construction, move assignment or a destructor, C++ would generate them all for you, simplifying your class to just:

Polynomial.h (now with nothing but the "from components" constructor and no assignment operators, because C++ makes them for you):

```
#pragma once
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Polynomial {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Polynomial&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Polynomial&);

public:
    // Default Constructor

    Polynomial(std::string coefficient = "1", std::string variable = "x",
        std::string exponent = "4");

    void setPolynomial(std::string, std::string, std::string);
    Polynomial getPolynomial();
    // addition operator; Polynomial + Polynomial
    Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial&) const;
    // subtraction operator; Polynomial - Polynomial
    Polynomial operator-(const Polynomial&) const;

private:
    std::string coefficient; // 
    std::string variable;    // 
    std::string exponent;    // 
};

#endif
```

Polynomial.cpp:

```
// Overloaded stream insertion and stream extraction operators
// for class PhoneNumber.
#include "Polynomial.h"
#include <utility>  // For std::move
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// default constructor; conversion constructor that converts
// Changed: Added actual initialization of fields from arguments (previously unused)
Polynomial::Polynomial(std::string co, std::string va, std::string ex) : coefficient(std::move(co)), variable(std::move(va)), exponent(std::move(ex)) {}
// Setters
void Polynomial::setPolynomial(std::string co, std::string va, std::string ex) {
    // Changed: Using std::move since we received by value, so we can empty
    // large strings more efficiently by transferring ownership from the copies that
    // are about to go away anyway
    this->coefficient = std::move(co);
    this->variable = std::move(va);
    this->exponent = std::move(ex);
}
// Getters
// Note: This function makes no sense; it's basically equivalent to just using the
// copy constructor, so if you have Polynomial a and b:
// a = b.getPolynomial();
// is just a long-winded way to spell:
// a = b;
// (and it won't work if b is const, because the function wasn't declared const)
Polynomial Polynomial::getPolynomial() { return *this; }
// overloaded stream insertion operator; cannot be a member function
// if we would like to invoke it with cout << somePhoneNumber;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Polynomial& number) {
    output << "Coefficient: " << number.coefficient
        << "\nVariable: " << number.variable
        << "\nExponent: " << number.exponent << "\n"
        << "" << number.coefficient << "" << number.variable << "^"
        << number.exponent << "\n";
    return output; // enables cout << a << b << c;
}

// overloaded stream extraction operator; cannot be a member function
// if we would like to invoke it with cin >> somePhoneNumber;
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Polynomial& number) {
    input >> setw(1) >> number.coefficient; // input area code
    input >> setw(1) >> number.variable;    // input exchange
    input >> setw(1) >> number.exponent;    // input line
    return input;                           // enables cin >> a >> b >> c;
}

// addition operator; Polynomial + Polynomial
// A member function takes an implicit first parameter
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial& op1) const {
    Polynomial temp; // temporary result

    if (this->variable == op1.variable) {
        if (this->exponent == op1.exponent) {
            // Use stoi string to int
            int num1 = stoi(this->coefficient);
            int num2 = stoi(op1.coefficient);
            // use to_string to set coefficient
            // Changed: Assigning result of std::to_string to coefficient directly
            // avoiding temporary std::string s that would just add more copy/move work
            temp.coefficient = std::to_string(num1 + num2);
            temp.variable = this->variable;
            temp.exponent = this->exponent;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Exponents must match\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Variables must match\n";
    }
    return temp; // return copy of temporary object
}
// substraction operator; Polynomial - Polynomial
// A member function takes an implicit first parameter
Polynomial Polynomial::operator-(const Polynomial& op1) const {
    Polynomial temp; // temporary result

    if (this->variable == op1.variable) {
        if (this->exponent == op1.exponent) {
            // Use stoi string to int
            int num1 = stoi(this->coefficient);
            int num2 = stoi(op1.coefficient);
            // Changed: Assigning result of std::to_string to coefficient directly
            // avoiding temporary std::string s that would just add more copy/move work
            temp.coefficient = std::to_string(num1 - num2);
            temp.variable = this->variable;
            temp.exponent = this->exponent;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Exponents must match\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Variables must match\n";
    }
    return temp; // return copy of temporary object
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vjfb9s2EH7XX0F4QGsvdoIkzoudGgiyYW/dgLV7KjZQEm2zkUhNpOy4Qf727I6UKFKW0mY/HlbUQBxJvPt4d9/d8eSkKGabJHl6@o6LJKtSRq65VLpkNF9F7TN4wsVmFUVJRpUiv8jsIGTOaUYeIgKfdcmZSInS6WJRq78ismAl1bK8vh4HC1OSSKG0h/JqsjyC4V2Y1WocLEw7AFFRxRlPFgbp7Iz8wNa0yjS5xc3KKgGIyKy1ahbQOgdGsfWaJ2CBJm/I6Hw0Jf7yjpacxhnDtfvR1CDhx5dh94UUtf58hDahxE5y8Inp/n2DXYKbOihesDcBSL0OrtI05ZpL4WK19LVOvJsuYqNwMj7mxNLkNlFVrEuaDO8z@4J9Zs/sExUl31HNLIMD1CzRlCOBhpxlbWs0xIwTeIT94P/PO1ZmkqYMsw7TinChWGmcpMI9ZPdHritUX8uS1CWxBfy3VR6z8jTyiymngherqFJohqA5UwVNGBpnLUjrNE3aNF3iDRimcD/vOdFbqus1bfa/3VKxYemC3KToAphYQbC5gGygGf9ErcVrsuYsSxXUl8wJLTdVDqFQZFyUbMdlpbIDqUSlWDqJWmIWi8FC6VbGtBPrCVn4nFntXO4YsD@ZTB1d3sKO4kJDk7cAaBPy8Ije/sq0hqhEpqB8QweL64tsfWgy3EXzvSHL2UDgFijbM1KyhPEdRDo@AFRWMUCTuJBQQVhe6EODlUGYkWXcRZFcloy4eEC4QR8ySqg1K40dci/Asy0vLEd6C5Cy4EwZzl2dAwqNZaWJlmQjCd3TA6TpAf4ZEb3larYKG1kQ@6Un5jW0gAZfxmtoASPLyBDyU00IXL6VULjkHWiRdSVsqeT0DhwQEpofFNWScP1akZgqntAMYsD@rKDeM4QHdz5W0BZslYD3CAkBOPjpb2LN1@QgK7KlQIvXX6ip1niBehSsjU@PeiWsgHFmG0oyKTazPRdYNRhEMEAVLMtaAKMwRlSuyV6K1/hd3qEBMQIZw6YkZgmFyjGMOcf3VKF8yqA3lLCDkfVrK8jejqXkAdJMV6Ug3yMJS2JCLZ9pVG03hjQUUoNR4EPOsBk5o4z/a8zVvayylGT8jqHbXOwkXKGTXG/BVMiu62sIdc68nraM@o719lmli0r3HOxEGPWmyKwc4o9u2yxdkBE@sqKnXvq6QxYVPojf6owN5Zs87gj/WKduKOwS2gqNAqUBK47WXOXgwu8BxsA2tqZqWm0QzEHGBOIoF3WKXzF@JVhi/cT3HEb/CvNckNXqmPi@Qcw948LwPsy4ETC4TO/H5xO8PA6xCYYVhYKhEI@UfU69e@ZbUXafmC7@Oe3uQGBFMy6YT5V5uiTDH59DGz@KXzF@OQpfMJ6B9E2XP6JNH4UThucFTLhA2JqXUGcFLWGegA481Fmeme7AlvN68qqZ8jA0HGWGEryQJS0PEBAFU4odaCGZxt0z5A0COk4a9kPp9jSx0s29L10H9b3Cw1Py@gS16aoDKbhHMs/N2ST5@Ojwq0@yjvxFI48WDEuDDaatyz9aCyCLSF936o4PN0rxjUAlGzWcwMzxGaD5HSblMFnAXNCFpDjqGHlHhD@92OmgLmt7sqWpHTbw8DwzwwueWgEuYp32DAnOurEJ64mJVicsRtebHMI06JH1JogwCVrZR3fFMgh5mAvGsqY9jpqmDhMVeptTnWxde22x7HcHLURqzpJepEe/B7hiqO/NWAKMtpTI@COwZ0cieEtSL3hN@m/qffat3v9GvX9l9Tv7Vr8vrd@o71ewCBMpp1zgaB51f0IiBVwa@ATENavBzOM@0YsXyF6@QHb@AtmrIVnrXMuWgF5jVmplOztBZdnXHVnm5OJ@vjCzMRNp5n4rqmehAufIes5U3vyIr79Nb4MXQa5UBWnbKCO2kGLWbYv41ugPobDJ1G4xsXbXmyIhoSMfxDvAPHaEoYPmDVAtXPKYN0@r2G8/juj/2H54e8JdQgeabcHQMKRfASUX/29ORsYH@y5pL4MAm3KFHmmoO@l12Io4gMtjgHkDMBsEmLcA82OAqxqgR/GqVbzyFR@fniBfokv4O7@f/wU)

Additional notes:

1. As written, failed `+` and `-` operations (due to mismatched variable/exponent) still behave as if they succeeded, returning a default initialized `Polynomial`. Sure, it dumps a log to `std::cout`, but the program still continues running with total garbage data. Those `std::cout` errors should really be exceptions, not simple logs.
2. Your comments claim the `+` and `-` operations return a copy of `temp`. While logically this true (it must be copyable to be used in that context), in most C++11 and later compilers, copy elision will occur (the new `Polynomial` will be constructed directly into the caller allocated storage; no *moves*, let alone *copies* will occur).